# memory allocation is very high when using specific DLL library. Maybe. Not sure what to do

Tags: .net, multithreading, memory, dll

Okay. I'm not entirely sure what the cause could even be, but I'm going to try to explain the factors that I *think* are related and hopefully someone can help! And I'll gladly answer anything else that might be missing. Long story short the code in question:

- Uses ITextSharp to check for page counts etc. in a a folder full of PDF's.
- Uses task.factories for threading (basically a main sub calls the "pdf counting" sub and the counting sub uses interlocked.add to add the pages to a public variable.)
- I use a very similar process (using a different library) to do the same thing for Tiff files. It doesn't appear to have the same issue.
- If I rerun the program without closing it first (just counting the files again) the mem usage in task manager will drop a little at first, but eventually ends up higher than the previous iteration. There seems to be a ceiling to that, but I haven't really tested it.
- Processor usage returns to normal when the program completes.

The problem I've run into is that the memory allocated to the program in the task manager becomes disproportionately large very quickly when I'm doing this (it bounces up and down some, but is usually between 300-700 mb when doing running this process on a few hundred files). It also continues to sit at that level of mem usage even when the program is "done" and just displaying the results on a form. Looking at tasks, threads etc. it all appears to be normal when the program is "done." But it appears something is still being stored in memory somewhere, somehow.

It's my vague understanding that Garbage Collection should deal with any cleanup when the sub ends, right? Even attempting to do a simple Using statement like:

```
    Using PDFDocx As PdfReader = New PdfReader(PDFToCount)
        Dim Pges As Integer = PDFDocx.NumberOfPages
        Interlocked.Increment(Pges)
    End Using
```

seems to make no difference at all. My whole understanding of managed vs. un-managed code is vague at best. Would this DLL constitute un-managed code, and if so, is that somehow the problem? Is the mem allocation in the task manager somehow an optical illusion? Or is it possible that using the task library like I am is causing the problem? I realize this is all a bit vague, and I'll gladly fill in any information I can.

Edit: As a followup, I used this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42721/Best-Practices-No-5-Detecting-NET-application-memo to lead me to using DebugDiag and getting the results that seem to indicate:

```
Function   clr!CExecutionEngine::ClrVirtualAlloc+4a 
Source Line    
Allocation type   Virtual memory allocation(s) 
Allocation Count   12 allocation(s) 
Allocation Size   1.8 GBytes 
Leak Probability   50%
```

is responsible for the issue. Any suggestions based on the new information?

Comment: " There seems to be a ceiling to that, but I haven't really tested it." - ???

Comment: Memory use as displayed in Task Manager or the equivalent is not a problem that needs to be solved. Memory usage as in running out of memory or as in too many hard faults, _is_ a problem to be solved.

Comment: @MitchWheat I suppose you could describe it as diminishing returns. The memory will continue to grow, but at a less severe rate. I'd say it seems to cap out after 4 or 5 iterations of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Perfmon to determine if your .NET application is leaking memory (managed or unmanaged).

Run Perfmon.exe and add these counters:

- Process / Private bytes
- .NET CLR Memory / # bytes in all heaps
- .NET CLR LocksAndThreads / # of current logical threads

Run your application for a representative length of time and exercise its functionality.

If **Private bytes** is increasing but **# bytes in all heaps** is not, then unmanaged memory is leaking. If **both** are increasing, then managed memory is leaking.

If the **# of current logical threads** is increasing beyond what you expect, then thread stacks are leaking.

If **Private Bytes** is periodically jumping in 1MB increments with a corresponding increase in # of current logical Threads, a thread stack leak is the likely cause.

From [here](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com.au/2010/11/determine-if-your-net-application-has.html).

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. I tried out PerfMon for a while. Few questions now. 1. I'm not sure how many logical threads I should be expecting? It seems to increase by a max of 30 or so while running, and is rather stable. Should the number drop when the "count" is done? 2. It appears both Bytes in all heaps and Private Bytes is increasing, the former increasing something like 500% while the latter more like 25%. What would you recommend from here?

Comment: Updated original thread with additional info that might help. Thanks again!